# Datawindow opening error "The memory could not read"

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm using PowerBuilder version 7.0.3. While opening/Modify Datawindow the datawindow from the library list i got the following error message

["The instruction at "0x104a985c" referenced memory at "0x00000000". The memory could not be "read"
Click on OK to termincate the program
Click on CANCEL to debug the program]

is there any solution for that issue?

how to resolve this?

Thanks! in advance

regards
Ambutbhath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you get this whenever you open *any* DataWindow into the DataWindow painter, that usually means there's been a corruption in the stored layouts. You need to go into the registry (backup before doing any registry work, of course) and delete the entries; PowerBuilder will rebuild them. Details are at [my Troubleshooting Guide](http://www.techno-kitten.com/PowerBuilder_Help/Troubleshooting/Abnormal_Termination/abnormal_termination.html#layouts). If this doesn't solve the issue, there are other ideas there you might pursue, like conflicting DLL versions.

Good luck,

Terry.